# After deserialization set property in class that wasn't in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

The class I made exists of a bunch of properties. Most of the properties are included in the received dataset. After the deserialization of the dataset, I retreive a list of objects. So some of the properties where ignored by using 'jsonignore'.

In the objects I have a property for example called 'foo'. I want this property to be set before I continue.

A possible solution could be looping through the list and setting the property. --> but this seems like double work, because all items were just looped in the deserialization of json.net. Is it possible to override the deserialization so the property I want is set after all other properties (that were in the dataset)?

Can someone get me started? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to achieve what you want:

1. set the property `foo` in the class'es constructor,
2. use a `CustomCreationConverter<T>` to instantiate the class and set `foo`; there's a good example in Json.NET's [documentation here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html),
3. use a `[OnDeserialized]` callback method; again, there's an [example here](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializationCallbacks.htm).